# Conditional formatting based on specific time value

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have an Excel worksheet that calculates the difference between two times; the arrival time of train services and the departure time of connecting bus services. No problem with that part (i.e. subtracting one time from the other) but what I wish to do is to highlight those connection times that are excessive and at the moment I have set this figure at 30 minutes.

I would like to use conditional formatting to highlight time differences that are greater than 30 minutes. Is this possible?

Comment: There is not enough information here to be able to really answer.  Is the cell only time no date data? In what cells are the times?... You can try something like this formula: `=A1>TIME(0,30,0)`

Comment: Greater than 30 minutes from what, the current time, another cell value? As @ScottCraner said, too little information.

Comment: Additionally, please consider including an image of your current setup and some sample (or real) data and an example of what you want the outcome to look like.

Comment: Could you provide a sample about this problem?

Comment: Thanks everyone for prompt replies. What this spreadsheet is doing is simply calculating the difference between two times - in more detail the arrival time of train services and the departure time of connecting bus services. No problem with that part (i.e. subtracting one time from the other) but what I am wishing to do is to highlight through conditional formatting those connection times that are excessive and at the moment I have set this figure at 30 minutes. Hope this info is sufficient.

Comment: Please don't add information in comments, it is better to [edit your question](https://superuser.com/posts/1442760/edit) instead. You may also want to take the time to [read this](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

You can set conditional formatting for the time difference column to highlight any value that is greater than your chosen threshold.

[image]

Note that I had to set the acceptable difference (in cell F1) to one second more than 30 minutes in order to avoid highlighting some differences of 30 minutes. This is because Excel stores times as fractions of a day, and floating point numbers can't represent these fractions exactly.